# Generate strings which have normal distribution length (Matlab)

Tags: string, matlab, normal-distribution

I have an initial string : S= 'ABCDEFGH'
How can I generate 100 strings from S where there is no repeated character in each string and the characters in each string will be in an order from 'A' to 'H' . Every string has diffent length which is based on normal distribution.Here, the mean=4, and sd = 1

The expected output (may be different because of random strings are genrated should be 100 srings like below:

```
 Output = { 'ABEGH'; 'ABE'; 'DH' ; 'BCGH' ..........; 'ABCDEGH'}
```

Thanks !

Comment: The normal distribution is not suitable here. It may give rise to negative values. Also, your requirements impose a maximum length of `8`, which again is incompatible with the length being a normal random variable

Comment: Could you check if you really want a normal distribution? It is often confused with a uniform distribution.

Comment: I think in this case, a discrete probability is needed rather than a continuous probability distribution.

Comment: At first sight, the problem does not seem completely defined. It is stated that the **number of letters** should be picked from a normal distribution, but nothing is said about how you pick the letters. Are they to be picked from a uniform distribution (which is of course not entirely uniform since a taken letter cannot be chosen again)? Apart from that, I would say that a set of 8 is to low to get a proper normal distribution. Truncation may become a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what distribution you want. This is a generic answer for any length distribution.

```
S = 'ABCDEFGH'; %// input characters
distr = [.1 .2 .1 .2 .1 .1 .1 .1]; %// probability of getting lengths 1, 2, ..., numel(S)
n = randsample(numel(distr), 1, 1, distr); %// random length with the specified distribution
ind = sort(randperm(numel(S), n)); %// take n sorted values from 1, ..., numel(S);
result = S(ind);
```

Assuming all permutations produced from `randperm` are equally likely<sup>1</sup> the above code, conditioned on a given `n`, generates all possible `n`-digit substrings with the same probability.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> 
In old Matlab versions `randperm` was an m-function. From its source code it was clear that it produced all permutations with the same probability. In recent versions it's not an m-function anymore, and its documentation doesn't specify that.</sup>

Comment: How about we just make random length ( forget about the normal distribution) , we can keep the minimum of length is 5? How can I generate 100 samples in the cell array Output from 'S' with the order from 'A' to 'H' ?

Comment: If you want minimum length 5, set the probabilities for all lower values to zero

Comment: And how can I generate 100 samples (strings) at 1 time. In you code, it just generate 1 sample

Comment: I don't see any better option than to put the last three lines in a loop to do this 100 times